# Create a music player in react native with specific control in React-Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, audio, audio-player

I am developing react native application, I want to create a music player application with some specific control like

1. Adjust the speed of the current playing audio file
2. And other options like Play the next track, play the previous track, and repeat the track

I have checked about this and created one small demo for the same with **[React-native-sound](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound)** but I am not getting a proper solution for it.

I need this functionality for android and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [react-native-track-player](https://github.com/doublesymmetry/react-native-track-player) and It still works as my expectation.

Comment: Can we set dynamic speed by using this package?

Comment: Yes, you can take a look at this function: https://react-native-track-player.js.org/docs/api/functions/player#setraterate